# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting - shuts down after GRUB

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown

I installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS on my new bought SSD. I was happy with it, despite I was having some random "freezes" with Chrome and when I do `sudo apt-get update`.

This morning I was trying to install Vivaldi browser, and after `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` Ubuntu just froze, and I had to shutdown holding the power button. When I tried to boot it again selecting the distro on GRUB menu, the computer just "shut down", with my monitor light blinking. I tried to change the quiet splash for nomodeset on Ubuntu boot edit, but instead, a purple screen remains forever.

By the way, I am running on AMD GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Live install of ubuntu already.

boot to it and reinstall grub or try to mount the installed ubuntu partition.

you could also install auto repair on the live install and try to fix the problem.